# WSO2 Identity Server - Force users to fill out security questions for password reset

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to force my users to fill out the security questions for self service password reset. Ideally when they log into a SP it reads our active directory for the custom attribute associated with the security questions. IF that is blank then force the user into the wso2is dashboard/security questions area.

IS THIS POSSIBLE????!!!!????

Thank you for any assistance.

I have looked through all of the wso2is documentation and forums looking for a solution, still have yet to come across anything.

Comment: Self service password reset with security questions is setup and working great, just need to force the users to do it!

Answer (score 2):

So I found the answer, it is now included in version 5.7. 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Managing+Challenge+Questions
Very bottom of article.
Upgrading is fine but if 5.7 can do it, 5.3 should also be able to. Oh well time to upgrade.